# Structuring data in an HDF store

Tags: python, mongodb, data-structures, pandas, hdf5

I'm working with a large number datasets, each a pandas DataFrame, which I need to access from disk because of the size of them.  From what I'm read, it looks like HDF would be a good way to work with them, but I'm a bit puzzled about the best way of structuring the data because of various bits of metadata which go with each DataFrame.  If I were to store the data in memory I could probably use something like a namedtuple (although this wouldn't allow for easy queries):

```
DataSet = namedtuple('DataSet', 'model method id data')
```

`data` is the attribute holding the actual dataframe, and the other fields are text.  However, I now need to include a series of results fields, which I would probably do in memory using a dict of DataFrames.  If I were to dump this to a mongodb, I would probably have something that looks like this:

```
[{
    model: 'mir',
    method: 'rfl_max',
    id: 's0001',
    data: <DataFrame>,
    results: [
        {
            option_r: 10,
            window: 30,
            data: <DataFrame>
        },
        ...
    ]
},
....
]
```

My basic question is can I efficiently apply this structure to HDF?  Specifically:

1. Does HDF support this sort of nesting, and if so how do I do it?
2. Looking up data like this is efficient in mongo because of how it uses indexes.  Is the same true for HDF, e.g. could I efficiently find all results matching a specific method and option_r?
3. My limited experience with HDF is through pandas, which appears to only allow Series, DataFrames on Panels to be stored.  Is this a realy limitation, or am I just doing something wrong?

Alternatively, does anyone know of a file based mongodb implementation which might serve my purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HDFStore` supports hierarchical indexing, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hierarchical-keys).

You can store attributes attached to a particular node, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#hdfstore). This is generally limited to a small amount of meta-data.

HDF5 is quite efficient at storing/searching the actual data, e.g. a DataFrame. The structure is up 2 you, but it is not meant to compete, rather it can complement `mongodb`. mongo is nice at keeeping/searching these 'json-like' kinds of nested structures.

You can always keep a reference to the actual location of the data (the DataFrame/Series) rather than the actual data in a mongo db.

HDF5 will be orders of magnitude faster for storing/searching the actual data (except for very small datasets).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So you're saying that any complex queries would be better done in mongo, but storing the data in HDF5 is good?  I'm trying to avoid mongo because it requires a central server (which I don't have access to), making it difficult to share data.  Each DataFrame is not huge, and at the moment I'm simply pickling them and loading them into memory, so perhaps I sould just continue with that,

Comment: Complex queries can certainly be done in HDF5. However, you cann't easily query the nodes themselves. See pytables.org more more info.